# IK Limit Rotation not working when using pole

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

The IK Limit works fine when the not using a pole, but when you add a pole object the limit of the bone stops working.

file: https://filebin.net/t4b8spnk9vuarpp9

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and it's a known issue.  What's the question?

Comment: Why does it not work with poles?